# Unable to setup Spring Config server with bibucket

Tags: bitbucket, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, jgit

I'm trying to set up Spring Boot Config Server for a few microservices from the Bitbucket repo(earlier while learning tutorial I did the same using Github, it worked, but I think bitbucket is a little different).

Have added dependencies in Config-Server build.gradle

> implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server'

Annotation added in the application class

> @EnableConfigServer

Modified .properties file to .yml, and configured like this

```
server:
  port: 8012
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
cloud:
  config:
    server:
    git:
      uri: ssh://bitbucket.org/project/repo.git
      ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
      clone-on-start: true
      passphrase: passphrase
      private-key: |
                   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                   Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
                   DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,***************************
                   
                   *************************************************
                   *************************************************
                   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Have gone through multiple other SO posts.
Tried with these ssh formats

> git@bitbucket.org:project/repo.git >> failed to send channel request

> ssh://git@bitbucket.org:project/repo.git >> extra / showed up because of jgit

> ssh://bitbucket.org/project/repo.git >> giving auth fail

Now I'm confused.
Did try adding this

> strict-host-key-checking: false

nothing changed

Any help what am I missing?

Comment: did you get any result? I'm too in the same condition